# Why is the hashtag symbol used in the context of a random color generator using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

New student to programming and one of our lessons on basic JavaScript covers a random color generator. The code is very well explained save for the '#' assigned to color. Can someone explain how this works; I've not had any success finding it online (and before anyone says it, hopefully my googling skills will vastly improve given time as well). Thank you!

```
<script>
    function getRandomColor(){
      let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      let color = '#';
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }
    function changeColor(){
      let newColor = getRandomColor();
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's just how the RGB syntax is - `#` followed by 6 hex digits

Comment: It comes for how HTML originally specified colors which was later adopted by CSS. For example `#ff0000` is red and `#ffff00` is yellow. Without the `#` is is not a color for example `ccff00` is cee cee eff eff zero zero. This syntax is actually much older than the web. Tcl/tk (the tk graphical toolkit of the tcl programming language) used the `#` syntax for colors before the web was invented.